# npx create-react-app myapp not creating project

Tags: reactjs

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\HI\appvid\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
>   node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
>
> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\HI\appvid\node_modules\core-js
>   node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
>
> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\HI\appvid\node_modules\core-js-pure
>   node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

- react@16.13.1
- react-scripts@3.4.1
- react-dom@16.13.1
- cra-template@1.0.3
  added 1606 packages from 750 contributors and audited 931196 packages in 626.818s

58 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the create-react-app (folder-name) command instead of using the npx create app command? Is it installed globally? What exactly do you write on the terminal?

Comment: I am creating project with command npx create-react-app projectname

Comment: Its not creating project properly with src and nodemodules ..it is creating only package.json